# Is 240 a major number in Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS?

Tags: drivers, 20.04

I am trying to load a module like this:

```
sudo insmod message_slot.ko
```

when the major number of `message_slot.ko` is 240 and I get:

```
insmod: error: could not insert module message_slot: device or resource busy
```

I checked with `lsmod` and the driver is not loaded before I am loading it.

Update:

`message_slot.ko` is a driver I wrote and using `register_chrdev(240, "msg_slot", &Fops)` in the `module_init`. When I am trying to load it with `register_chrdev(2, "msg_slot", &Fops)` instead it is working.

Comment: I'm confused by your question.  Libraries can have any number of version numbers, not necessarily related to a specific Ubuntu version.  Some libraries, etc. exist for a long time and dont' get changed.  You mention a 'major number' of 'message_slot.ko' - are you saying you've tried other versions of this and it hasn't worked?  (You might need to file a bug specific for your hardware if it can't load in your system)

Comment: @ThomasWard I updated my question with an answer to your question. Is it clearer now?

Comment: @DougSmythies what do you mean by a left over version? I tried `ls -l -a /dev/msg_slot` but I get an error message: `ls: cannot access "/dev/msg_slot": No such file or directory`

Comment: @DougSmythies well I don't see the nvme drive on my machine. Any way I am pretty sure that a Major number cannot be reused.

Answer (score 0):

If the major version of 240 is already used for a character device, then it should be present in `/dev/char`. Example:

```
doug@s19:~/temp-k-git/linux$ ls -l /dev/char | grep 240:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  8 May 10 20:23 240:0 -> ../nvme0
doug@s19:~/temp-k-git/linux$
```

See the [devices.txt](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/admin-guide/devices.txt) document in the kernel tree.

I assume your "resource busy" error is because the 240 major version number is already used by something.

EDIT: Perhaps a better way to see what major numbers are already used is to look at `/proc/devices`. Example:

```
doug@s19:~/c$ cat /proc/devices
Character devices:
  1 mem
  4 /dev/vc/0
  4 tty
  4 ttyS
  5 /dev/tty
  5 /dev/console
  5 /dev/ptmx
  5 ttyprintk
  7 vcs
 10 misc
 13 input
 21 sg
 29 fb
 89 i2c
108 ppp
116 alsa
128 ptm
136 pts
180 usb
189 usb_device
202 cpu/msr
203 cpu/cpuid
204 ttyMAX
226 drm
234 mei
235 hidraw
236 aux
237 cec
238 ttyDBC
239 lirc
240 nvme-generic
241 nvme
242 vfio
243 bsg
244 watchdog
245 remoteproc
246 ptp
247 pps
248 rtc
249 dma_heap
250 dax
251 dimmctl
252 ndctl
253 tpm
254 gpiochip

Block devices:
  7 loop
  8 sd
  9 md
 11 sr
 65 sd
 66 sd
 67 sd
 68 sd
 69 sd
 70 sd
 71 sd
128 sd
129 sd
130 sd
131 sd
132 sd
133 sd
134 sd
135 sd
253 device-mapper
254 mdp
259 blkext
```

Which shows cec, as per the comment, but with major number 237 on my system.

The suggestion for the users is to use dynamic assignment of the major instead of static, letting the system decide. [Reference](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/linux-device-drivers/0596000081/ch03s02.html).

Comment: Ok so I didn't find anything with major = 240 at `/dev/char`, but I did see something in `/proc/devices`. When calling `cat /proc/devices | grep 240` I get `240 cec`. So I believe that this is the module that holding the major 240. Now I'm just wondering if I should remove this module or try to switch it's major...

Comment: `grep 240 /proc/devices` -> `240 nvidia-nvlink` on my machine.